# Using rotatebox and multicol in a table for the same cell

Tags: tables, multicol, rotating

I have a table which has column headings like this:

[image]

There is a gap between the row with text beginning 'Segments...' and the numbering of the second row. I believe this is due to my use of `\rotatebox` for text 'Pair' as per the following code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{rcccccccccc}%{*{11}l}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} &
        \multicolumn{10}{c}{\textbf{Segments and days of tranche}} \\
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Pair}}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{1}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{2}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{3}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{4}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{5}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{6}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{7}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{8}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{9}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{10}} \\
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{28-30(31)}} &       
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{13-15}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{01-03}} &        
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{16-18}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{19-21}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{04-06}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{22-24}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{10-12}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{25-27}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{07-09}} \\  
        \midrule

        . . .

        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular} 
    \caption{...}
    \label{tab:...}
\end{table}
```

Is there any way the text 'Pair' can be aligned so that it remains rotated but where the gap is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Code for above table is:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{booktabs,makecell,rotating}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont pair}

    \usepackage[margin=25mm,showframe]{geometry}

    \begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{r*{11}{l}}
    \toprule
    &   \multicolumn{10}{c}{\thead{Segments and days of tranche}}   \\
\rothead{\textbf{Pair}} &
\thead{1\\ 28-30(31)} &
    \thead{2\\ 13-15} &
        \thead{3\\ 01-03} &
            \thead{4\\ 16-18} &
                \thead{5\\ 19-21} &
                    \thead{6\\ 04-06} &
                        \thead{7\\ 22-24} &
                            \thead{8\\ 10-12} &
                                \thead{9\\ 25-27} &
                                    \thead{10\\ 07-09}              \\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{11}{c}{\dots}                                          \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\caption{My important table}
    \label{tab:xxx}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

In table design I use behind package `booktabs` (for table rules) packages `makecell` which define macros `thead˛` dedicated for column heads and `rothead` which for its work need package `rotating`.

**Adedendum:** since I do not know, what is content of first columns, I in above MWE left for it natural width. If it is desired to be more narrow, this can be achieved with manual tuning of its width for example as:

```
\begin{tabular}{|@{\hskip-1ex}c@{\ }*{11}{l|}}
```